# How to make an select request from an DbContext object in EntityFramework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my first post so don’t shoot me if the question is stupid. I am new at entity framework and I’m trying to select a single thing in a table.  
I found some things where you could just enter a where statement but it seems not to work in the EF7. And yes I have to use EM7 although it’s not finished jet because it is a requirement of my project.

```
var result = from Context.Addresses where Address.Id = addressId;
```

Comment: _"it seems not to work"_ - why not? Care to share the exact compiler error? Did you try reading a LINQ tutorial?

Comment: try this =>var resulat=from item in context.addresses where item.id==addressId

Comment: your query syntax LINQ seems wrong, looks like it should be `from Address in Context.Addresses where Address.Id == addressId select Address`.